# Hidden value <p>

Tags: php, html, hidden, bootstrap-modal

I want to know how to hidden `p` value but remain the value in the table. How to do it?
This is the code

```
<p id="session"></p>
```

If value in input text field we can hidden the value by using this code `hidden="hidden"`. Value still in the table but user can not see it.

thanks,
faizal.

Comment: I'm not sure anybody will understand the question here - please could you clarify what you mean by "reamin the value in the table"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's supposed to be a value in a form (which I presume from your reference to `<input>`, then you can make it a hidden form field.

```
<input type="hidden" value="**the value**" id="session" />
```

However, this will still be visible to a user who looks into the source code of the page. You might find it better to store the value in a session if you don't want the user to know it at all.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
<style>
    #session {
        display:none;
    }   
</style>

<p id="session"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understand the question correctly but you can just put display:none on the P

Comment: not in the P but in style tag.

<style>
    #session {
        display:none;
    }   
</style>

<p id="session"></p>
anyway thank you sir :B

Comment: You *can* do it directly on the P:  <P id="session" style="display:none">